# working with NMEA data sent to URL/IP

Tags: python, django, nmea

i have a bunch of devices that send NMEA sentences to a URL/ip. 
that look like this

"$GPGGA,200130.0,3447.854659,N,11014.636735,W,1,11,0.8,41.4,M,-24.0,M,,*53"

i want to read this data in, parse it and upload the key parts to a database. i know how to parse it and upload it to the DB but i am at a complete loss on how to "read"/accept/get the data into a python program so that i can parse and upload.

my first thought was to point it at a Django page and then have Djanog parse it and upload to the database (data will be accessed from Django site) but its a NMEA sentence not a HTTP request so Django rejects it as "message Bad request syntax"

what is the best (python) way to read NMEA sentences sent to a url/IP?

thanks

Comment: what? ....  what url is it going to? surely you must match at least that (NMEA is really easy to parse and work with ... Im just not sure what the question really is here) ... I may make some assumtions and post a solution below ... if my assumtions are wrong then clearly my solution will be wrong as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have some hardware that has an ethernet connection, and it pipes out the NMEA string over its ethernet connection.  this probably defaults to having some random 192.168.0.x ip address and spitting out data over port 12002 or something

you would typically create a socket to listen for this incomming data

**server.py**

```
import socket
host = "" #Localhost
port = 12002 
PACKET_SIZE=1024 # how many characters to read at a time
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(5) # we should never have more than one client
def work_thread(client):
    while True: #continuously read and handle data
      data = client.recv(PACKET_SIZE)
      if not data:
          break # done with this client
      processData(data)

while True:
     client,addr = sock.accept() # your script will block here waiting for a connection
     t = threading.Thread(target=work_thread,args=(client,))
     t.start()
```

sometimes however you need to ping the device to get the data

**client.py**

```
import socket
host = "192.168.0.204" #Device IP
port = 12002 
PACKET_SIZE=1024 # how many characters to read at a time
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,port)) #connect to the device
while True: #continuously read and handle data
    data = sock.recv(PACKET_SIZE)
    processData(data)
```

Comment: you rock this works. the data comes from a cellular router that has a GPS chip. the router sends that GPS data as a NMEA sentence to a give url/port (over the cell connection).

Comment: ahhh I see now ... I was totally baffled ... I had not seen this come over a webservice before

Comment: QUESTION will this handle multiple device connecting at the same time? or will this program only work for the one device

Comment: It would need to be a little different for more clients ... is each device sending a constant stream of data? or just intermittently connecting and sending most recent?

Comment: sends it at a user (admin) defined interval. i'm thinking ever 30 seconds would be good. my end goal would be to show a bread crumb trail on a map.  in the long run i could see having 500 maybe 1000 devices sending in data. so i would just set sock.listen(n) to my current max devices?

Comment: you have been so much help already and i would hate to keep bothering you. do you know of any resources that might help me work through this?

Comment: google : echo socket server ... its obviously not NMEA but will probably help