# Can not decode gps receiver data

Tags: python, bluetooth, gps, decode, nmea

I try to get nmea data from bluetooth gps receiver. But can't decode received data. This is my code;

```
import bluetooth

# Set the MAC address of the Bluetooth device you want to connect to
target_address = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'

# Search for nearby Bluetooth devices
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
print(nearby_devices)
# Loop through the nearby devices and try to connect to the target device
for address in nearby_devices:
    if address == target_address:
        # Try to connect to the target device
        print(f"Connecting to {target_address}...")
        
        try:
            # Create a Bluetooth socket and connect to the target device
            sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
            sock.connect((target_address, 1))


            # Receive some data from the target device
            try:
                while True:
                    
                    
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    
                    try:
                        print("Received", data)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
            except OSError:
                print(OSError)
        except Exception as e:
            # Failed to connect to the target device
            print(f"Failed to connect to {target_address}")
            print(e)
            pass
```

Example datas;

```
Received b'\xaaD\x12\x1c\xaf\x00\x00\x02,\x00\x00\x00Z\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x10\xee~\xaaD\x12\x1c*\x00\x00\x02H\x00\x00\x00b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*5\x00\x00,5\x12\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x112\xe0U\xaaD\x12\x1c\xae\x00\x00\x02\x1c\x00\x00\x00b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Received b'*5\x00\x00d\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07g@r'
Received b'\xaaD\x12\x1c\xaf\x00\x00\x02,\x00\x00\x00Z\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x10\xee~\xaaD\x12\x1c*\x00\x00\x02H\x00\x00\x00b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x129\x00\x00\x149\x12\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\xfe\xdax\xaaD\x12\x1c\xae\x00\x00\x02\x1c\x00\x00\x00b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

When try decode with utf-8;

```
['DC:0D:30:00:22:61']
Connecting to DC:0D:30:00:22:61...
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: invalid continuation byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 39: unexpected end of data
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 39: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 36: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 37: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
Received
R♥d↕↑Sз
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0: invalid continuation byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 36: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 37: invalid start byte
```

When try decode with ascii;

```
['DC:0D:30:00:22:61', 'B8:8E:82:F8:99:BF']
Connecting to DC:0D:30:00:22:61...
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Normally data should look like this : $GPGGA,210230,3855.4487,N,09446.0071,W,1,07,1.1,370.5,M,-29.5,M,,*7A

What do i have to decode it?

Comment: You should check the manufacturer's website for a manual on how the data is sent

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550514/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-gps-module-coming-with-nmea-protocol-through-a-serial and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160010/working-with-nmea-data-sent-to-url-ip

Comment: You are not getting NMEA data. Many GPS support NMEA, but by default they transfer data in binary form (much much more efficient). You should send a command to your unit, to set the format as text.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with GPS. I contacted the company that sold the device. They sent me configuration commands.